# Windows Async Profiler Error in IntelliJ while trying to run Application with Profiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiling, async-profiler

I am getting this error `"Profiler error: There is no dump file"` in the profiler tab while running Application with Windows Async Profiler.

Environment- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, Java 8

I am new to Profiling and I am just starting to learn. Java Flight Recorder works fine but I'm getting this error for Windows Async Profiler. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [IDEA-270240](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270240), to use Windows async profiler with JDK 8 please try IDEA 2021.3 RC: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. In 2021.2 please use jdk 9 at least.

Comment: Does that mean profiling doesn't work in IntelliJ with Java 8?

Comment: No, it does not. After 2021.3 version of IntelliJ IDEA, profiling works with Java 8

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean "After 2021.3 version of IntelliJ IDEA, profiling **doesn't work** with Java 8"?